# Can I pre select options and/or site template on the New Subsite Page?

Tags: 2013, site, sub-site

I have a Sharepoint 2013 Site Collection where I allow super users to create new Subsites using a Custom Site Template.

I have a link on the Main page to go to the 'New Site' page, but I would like to pre-select the Custom Site Template, and some of the options on that page. Doing this would lower the possibility of user error, and would also allow me to change/update the custom site template without confusing users.

I was initially thinking I could do this using a QueryString of some sort, but now I'm not too sure. Is this at all possible, and how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can automatically select the option without altering master pages somewhere, but you can do it either with web services & workflow or server side code.

[Here's](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5044/programmatically-create-site-using-custom-web-template-in-sharepoint-2010) an example of someone doing it on StackExchange using c#, but in short it's using this sort of format:

```
SPWeb newWeb = siteCollection.Add(“/” + siteUrl, siteName, “site description”, 1033,{Name of the Site Template}, ownerLogin,ownerName,ownerEmail );
```

[Here's](https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8661/create-site-from-template-using-sharepoint-2013-workflow) an example of someone using the REST service and SP workflow to get it done using the /_api/web/webinfos/add end point and passing in the template GUID.