# Is it possible to duplicate a subsite using the C# client side object model

Tags: development, web-part, client-object-model, sub-site

I need to create a large amount of sub sites. Each one will be the exact same to support various products.  I have code written already to create a subsite and add the apps to it, but its proving to be a lot of work to create the pages to look the way that i want. If i manually create a subsite and make it exactly the way i want it, is it possible to just duplicate this subsite and give it a different name?

I cant seem to find code anywhere that will allow me to set what web parts i want  to show on the home page. This would make things so much quicker to get this done.

I am using the client side object model with a C# application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save a site as a template (through Site Settings GUI). When create sites using this templates with different name etc.

1. Instruction how to save site http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/11/23/how-to-save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint-2013/
2. Here http://get-spscripts.com/2011/02/finding-site-template-names-and-ids-in.html and [Programmatically create Site using Custom Web Template in Sharepoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5044/programmatically-create-site-using-custom-web-template-in-sharepoint-2010) how to find Site Template Name and ID
3. Then you this "wci.WebTemplate = "STS#0";" - just change Name and ID

Comment: Do you have any guide that shows how to do this? When creating a subsite i  can define the "wci.WebTemplate = "STS#0";". Can i replace this value with the file path of the template?

Comment: I have a .wsp file, but when i try to use the file path as the template it throws an exception. How should this template be used?

Comment: I've edited my comment. I dont think you have to use WSP itself.

Comment: The template that i have created is correctly showing up under the "Solution Gallery". When i run "Get-SPWebTemplate" in powershell, i dont see the templates that i created.

Comment: Try $site = Get-SPSite “http://portal”  #new line#    
    $site.GetWebTemplates(1033) | format-list name, title - don't forget to use your locale - it could differ from "1033" - do you see you template in the output? -

Comment: This worked. I am using C# for this, but the same method worked to get the data. Thanks for the help!